# List of open ports for Draytek Router

Tags: firewall, draytek

We are using a Draytek router for both the router and the firewall.

I am doing some auditing and wanted to know if there was a way to get a list of the open ports off the router without going through them 1-by-1.

Draytek Vigor 2952 is the router.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a port scanner?

Comment: Is that accurate for auditing purposes? 
I was hoping for an export of the ports as a CSV that I could then use for auditing, i.e. tracking changes weekly etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There is a CLI and it can be used to display open ports.

1) enable the SSH interface using the web GUI

2) access the CLI via SSH using the usual credentials

3) use the command `show openport` to display the open ports

The Draytek CLI reference document is [here](https://www.draytek.co.uk/support/downloads/software/send/336-software/696-draytek-cliref-1-12).